# Criar foreach com resultado de outro foreach

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Tenho um Curso e esse curso tem 1 ou vários Módulos, e cada Módulo tem 1 ou várias disciplinas. No meu controller fiz assim:

```
$_modSelecionados = Modulo::select('id_modulo')->where('id_curso', $curso)->get();
$modSelecionados = [];
foreach ($_modSelecionados as $modulo) {
   $modSelecionados[] = $modulo->id_modulo;

   // Pega as Disciplinas do Módulo
   $_discSelecionadas = DisciplinaModulo::select('id_disciplina')->where('id_modulo', $modSelecionados)->get();
   $discSelecionadas = [];
       foreach ($_discSelecionadas as $disciplina) {
           $discSelecionadas[] = $disciplina->id_disciplina;
       }
}
```

Passei tudo que preciso pra View e montei assim:

```
@foreach($modulos as $modulo)
@if(in_array($modulo->id_modulo, $modSelecionados) ? 'selected' : '')
    <table>
       <thead>
          <tr>
              <th scope="col"><i class="fal fa-long-arrow-down"></i>{{ $modulo->nome }}</th>
              <th scope="col">Carga Horária</th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          @foreach($disciplinas as $disciplina)
             @if(in_array($disciplina->id_disciplina, $discSelecionadas) ? 'selected' : '')
             <tr>
                 <td style="width: 65%;">{{ $disciplina->nome }}</td>
                 <td>{{ $disciplina->carga_horaria }} horas</td></tr>
             @endif
          @endforeach
      </tbody>
      </table>
  @endif
@endforeach
```

O que ta acontecendo é que gera uma tabela para cada MÓDULO, mas repete as DISCIPLINAS do módulo 1 para o módulo 2. Não busca as disciplinas do Módulo 2. Como na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como resolver isso???

Comment: Não entendi quem votou negativo para a pergunta, ela demonstra uma dúvida óbvia de um iniciante no framework e deve ser respeitada pois não fere as diretrizes do stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na sua lógica o problema é passar a coleção de disciplinas inteira sem distinguir qual a relação com cada módulo.

De qualquer forma, esta não é a melhor maneira de trabalhar com Laravel e Eloquent.

Altere o código em seus modelos para inserir os relacionamentos como descrito na documentação. Segue um exemplo:

```
class Modulo extends Model {
    // função com o relacionamento
    public function disciplinas() {
        // se o id chave estrangeira na tabela disciplina para modulo estiver
        // nos padrões descritos na documentação do Laravel
        return $this->hasMany(Disciplina::class);
    }
}
```

No controlador

```
$modulos = Modulo::where('id_curso', $curso)->get();
```

Na view

```
@foreach($modulos as $modulo)
    <hr/>
    <p>{{ $modulo->nome }}</p>
    <p>Disciplinas</p>
    @foreach ($modulo->disciplinas as $disciplina)
        <p>{{ $disciplina->nome }}</p>
    @endforeach
@foreach
```

O exemplo está simplificado, porém é apenas para demonstrar a relação entre os modelos e como recuperar usando o "jeito" Eloquent.

Desta maneira, cada módulo retorna suas disciplinas diretamente pela propriedade descrita em sua classe modelo.

Comment: No caso as Disciplinas estão na tabela de ralacionamento Disciplina_Modulo. Na tabela Disciplina tenho os dados dela, na tabela Módulo tenho os dados dele e o Curso. Mas a relação de disciplinas para cada módulo fica na tabela de ligação Disciplina_Modulo. O que muda? Como vou pegar o nome da Disciplina?

Comment: Mazer consegui resolver! Fiz assim no Model de Módulo:

return $this->belongsToMany("App\Models\Admin\Disciplina", 'disciplina_modulo', 'id_modulo', 'id_disciplina');

Carregou para cada Módulo suas Disciplinas. Muito obrigado pela ajuda amigo, e obrigado também por comentar sobre a pergunta, realmente é meu primeiro projeto em Laravel e estou apanhando pra algumas coisinhas. Muito obrigado

Comment: Ótimo, que bom ter podido ajudar